# Can we make a battery with a semiconductor?

Tags: batteries, semiconductors

Can we make battery with separate P and N junctions?

Comment: That depends on what you call a battery. Would you call a thermopile a battery?

Comment: Search for [how do thermoelectric generators work?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+does+a+themoelectric+generator+work&t=opera&ia=web)

Comment: But in thermoelectric generator have close circuit but here we don't, am i wrong

Comment: It's called a solar "cell" for a reason -- incoming light produces electron-hole pairs that can power external circuitry.

Answer (score 3):

There is no external potential normally produced across a P-N junction, if that's what you mean.

But if you take some tritium and bundle it up with a P-N junction (or many such junctions) you can make a [betavoltaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betavoltaic_device) battery.

Such a battery was commercially produced for use in pacemakers many decades ago (1970s). It had an open-circuit voltage of about 4.7V and a short circuit current of about 115uA. Due to the Promethium-147 isotope used the lifetime was not very long (2.62 years half-life).

Image from:

> (Matheson, W. E. (1975). The Betavoltaic Pacemaker Power Source.
> Engineering in Medicine, 401–424. doi:10.1007/978-3-642-66187-7_25

[image]

Comment: I would love to see a schematic of a pacemaker from the '70s, probably some very clever engineering went into it given the components available at the time.  (Not to mention having to work from a betavoltaic battery.)

Comment: Actually found some early pacemaker schematics online: http://www.vhlab.umn.edu/atlas/umn-cv-history/1957-58.shtml and https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-evolution-of-pacemakers-Haddad-Houben/801bd26db8631559849d36d56cd7f69c3cccacba/figure/7 as well as other places.

Comment: Imagine the results of a circuit oversight or a (gulp) software bug being the immediate death of a human being. The early ones, according to your link, were virtually unregulated and subjected to limited testing because the patients were as good as dead either way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of. In a manner of speaking.

Charge storage in PN junctions works just like a battery, in that population densities of charge carriers determine the available charge, and terminal voltage as the logarithm of their concentration.

The "manner of speaking" comes along, because, as far as I know, no semiconductors exist (or probably can exist) with recombination lifetimes longer than some ~ms.  So... it behaves as a battery, perhaps, but only on extremely short timescales (~µs), above which, self-discharge is utterly dominant.

For point of reference, a typical 2N3904 bipolar transistor has a self-discharge rate of around 20µs, as for a saturated switch with no turn-off base drive current, or the turn-off time of an avalanche-mode switch.

---

As mentioned by others, there are ways to inject charge into such a junction -- light being another example.  Photovoltaic panels operate on this principle; the difference is, because charge is constantly being separated (by incoming light), the logarithmic V(I) characteristic of the battery is limited by that light, rather than by what charge happens to be stored (which again, can be removed in mere microseconds otherwise).

Comment: I'm talking about separate p and separate n semiconductor with dielectric between them and then we give energy to move electron.

Comment: @KunjSolanki If there's no current path then it doesn't matter what they're made of, there's no current flow and certainly not a battery.

Comment: I'm thinking it like capacitor

Answer (score 0):

P-type and N-type silicon do not make suitable electrodes for a battery cell because they are essentially pure silicon.

Cells work by having different chemicals on each electrode and exploiting the difference in electronegativity.

Attempting to use doped silicon would quickly result in the surface dopant being dissolved in the electrolyte and after that only pure silicon would be in contact with the electrolyte. thus with both electrodes exactly matched there would be no EMF.

A cell that oxidises silicon itself would produice silocondioxide on the electrode surface, silicondioxide does not conduct electricity or dissolve in any safe chemicals so that would leave the cell open-circuit after only using a fraction of the electrode.